# Can't verify MomentOfInertia of a MeshRegion

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, mesh

In this simple **modified(thanks @DanielHuber) example** I create a volumemesh of a region

```
pts={{8.26, 7.89, 4.16}, {6.7, 5.82, 7.11}, {7.68, 1.76, 1.73}, {4.09,6.63, 2.6}, {9.97, 7.27, 7.76}, {7.76, 8.51, 9.03}, {6.66, 0.42,3.65}, {5.08, 5.85, 4.8}, {9.97, 6.78, 2.5}, {9.54, 9.39,9.67}}
vmesh = DelaunayMesh[pts]
```

[image]

and evaluate MomentOfInertia of vmesh

```
momI=MomentOfInertia[vmesh,{0,0,0}]
(*{{4005.93, -1478.38, -2857.63}, {-1478.38,5153.5, -1756.68}, {-2857.63, -1756.68, 3689.64}}*)
```

From documentation `MomentOfInertia`

```
NIntegrate[{{y^2 + z^2, -x y, -x z}, {-x y,x^2 + z^2, -y z}, {-x z, -y z, x^2 + y^2}} , Element[{x, y, z}, vmesh]]    
(*{{5310.13, -3820.05, -3213.79}, {-3820.05, 7321.74, -2519.15}, {-3213.79, -2519.15,8184.27}}*)
```

should give the same result, but differs significantly!

Any explanation why?
Thanks!

**addendum**

Probably 3D-DelaunayMesh causes the problems.
Using `ToElementMesh`

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
fem = ToElementMesh[pts] 
vmesh = MeshRegion[fem , PlotTheme -> "Lines"]         

momI = MomentOfInertia[vmesh, {0, 0, 0}] 
(*{{5309.13, -3819.78, -3213.91}, {-3819.78,7322.51, -2519.1}, {-3213.91, -2519.1, 8182.24}}*)
NIntegrate[{{y^2 + z^2, -x y, -x z}, {-x y,x^2 + z^2, -y z}, {-x z, -y z, x^2 + y^2}},Element[{x, y, z}, vmesh]]
(*{{5310.13, -3820.05, -3213.79}, {-3820.05, 7321.74, -2519.15}, {-3213.79, -2519.15, 8184.27}}*)
```

shows good agreement between the two solutions

Comment: MomentOfInertia[vmesh] gives the moment relative to the center of mass. On the other hand, your integral gives the moment  relative to the origin.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for your hint. I tried `MomentOfInertia[vmesh, {0, 0, 0}]` but it still differs.

Comment: @DanielHuber See my modified answer!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would report it to Wolfram. If they have something interesting to say, please report it here.

Comment: `MomentOfInertia[BoundaryMesh[vmesh], {0, 0, 0}]` also agrees with `NIntegrate`.

Comment: `ConvexHullMesh` and `ConvexHullRegion` also work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274687/4346) I think this has to do with inconsistently oriented cells, which [`MeshCellMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellMeasure.html) helps demonstrate.

We can repair just as in the other answer and get the correct moments.

```
vols = AnnotationValue[{vmesh, 3}, MeshCellMeasure]
```

> ```
> {-7.89684, 1.50617, 0.261745, -0.242213, 11.3958, 11.4174, 
>  11.9869, 4.53974, -6.16916, -5.22827, -4.82166, -2.96329, 2.55122, 
>  4.01713, 3.82906, 1.21645, 4.77329, -3.79328}
> ```

```
vmeshrepair = MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[vmesh], 
  MapThread[
    If[#2 >= 0, Identity, Reverse] /@ #1 &, 
    {MeshCells[vmesh, 3], vols}
  ]
];

MomentOfInertia[vmeshrepair, {0, 0, 0}]
```

> ```
> {{5309.13, -3819.78, -3213.91}, {-3819.78, 7322.51, -2519.1}, {-3213.91, -2519.1, 8182.24}}
> ```