# What's wrong with `Volume[]` of 3D-DelaunyMesh?

Tags: regions, mesh

For a DelaunayMesh of a set of points

```
pts = {{8.26, 7.89, 4.16}, {6.7, 5.82, 7.11}, {7.68, 1.76,1.73}, {4.09, 6.63, 2.6}, {9.97, 7.27, 7.76}, {7.76, 8.51,9.03}, {6.66, 0.42, 3.65}, {5.08, 5.85, 4.8}, {9.97, 6.78,2.5}, {9.54, 9.39, 9.67}};

vmesh =  DelaunayMesh[pts];
FindMeshDefects[vmesh ]
```

which seems to be ok, I observed differences calculating the volume:

```
Volume[vmesh] (* 26.3802 *)
MeshPrimitives[vmesh, 3] // Volume // Total (*88.6096*)
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at the measure of each cell. Some are negative, which I think means their orientation needs to be flipped.

```
vols = AnnotationValue[{vmesh, 3}, MeshCellMeasure]
```

> ```
> {-7.89684, 1.50617, 0.261745, -0.242213, 11.3958, 11.4174, 
>  11.9869, 4.53974, -6.16916, -5.22827, -4.82166, -2.96329, 2.55122, 
>  4.01713, 3.82906, 1.21645, 4.77329, -3.79328}
> ```

We can manually flip:

```
vmeshrepair = MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[vmesh], 
  MapThread[
    If[#2 >= 0, Identity, Reverse] /@ #1 &, 
    {MeshCells[vmesh, 3], vols}
  ]
];

Volume[vmeshrepair]
```

> ```
> 88.6096
> ```

---

A workaround:

```
meshMeasure[mr_] := 
  Total[Abs[AnnotationValue[{mr, RegionDimension[mr]}, MeshCellMeasure]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

- Althought `FindMeshDefects` does not show any defects, but `RepairMesh` with method seems fixed its defects.
- @Greg Hurst suggest `BoundaryMesh`  also fixed this.

```
RepairMesh[vmesh, {"FlippedFaces", "OverlappingFaces"}] // Volume
vmesh // BoundaryMesh // Volume
```

- the output of `DelaunayMesh` not as good as

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts]
ConvexHullRegion[pts]
```